# Destructured iteration over variadic arguments like a tuple sequence in D

Tags: foreach, tuples, d, variadic

Let's say I want to process a variadic function which alternately gets passed start and end values of 1 or more intervals and it should return a range of random values in those intervals. You can imagine the input to be a flattened sequence of tuples, all tuple elements spread over one single range.

```
import std.meta; //variadic template predicates
import std.traits : isFloatingPoint;
import std.range;

auto randomIntervals(T = U[0], U...)(U intervals)
if (U.length/2 > 0 && isFloatingPoint!T && NoDuplicates!U.length == 1) {
    import std.random : uniform01;
    
    T[U.length/2] randomValues;
    // split and iterate over subranges of size 2
    foreach(i, T start, T end; intervals.chunks(2)) {   //= intervals.slide(2,2)
        randomValues[i] = uniform01 * (end - start) + start,
    }
    return randomValues.dup;
}
```

The example is not important, I only use it for explanation. The chunk size could be any finite positive `size_t`, not only `2` and changing the chunk size should only require changing the number of loop-variables in the foreach loop.

In this form above it will not compile since it would only expect one argument (a range) to the foreach loop. What I would like is something which rather automatically uses or infers a sliding-window as a tuple, derived from the number of given loop-variables, and fills the additional variables with next elements of the range/array + allows for an additional index, optionally. According to the [documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/statement.html#foreach-with-ranges) a range of tuples allows destruct*ur*ing of the tuple elements in place into foreach-loop-variables so the first thing, I thought about, is turning a range into a sequence of tuples but didn't find a convenience function for this.

Is there a *simple* way to loop over destructured subranges (with such a simplicity as shown in my example code) together with the index? Or is there a (standard library) function which does this job of splitting a range into enumerated tuples of equal size? How to easily turn the range of subranges into a range of tuples?

Is it possible with `std.algorithm.iteration.map` in this case (EDIT: with a simple function argument to map and without accessing tuple elements)?

EDIT: I want to ignore the last chunk which doesn't fit into the entire tuple. It just is not iterated over.

EDIT: It's not, that I couldn't program this myself, I only hope for a simple notation because this use case of looping over multiple elements is quite useful. If there is something like a "spread" or "rest" operator in D like in JavaScript, please let me know!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Added as a separate answer because it's significantly different from my previous answer, and wouldn't fit in a comment)

After reading your comments and the discussion on the answers thus far, it seems to me what you seek is something like the below `staticChunks` function:

```d
unittest {
    import std.range : enumerate;
    size_t index = 0;
    foreach (i, a, b, c; [1,2,3,1,2,3].staticChunks!3.enumerate) {
        assert(a == 1);
        assert(b == 2);
        assert(c == 3);
        assert(i == index);
        ++index;
    }
}

import std.range : isInputRange;

auto staticChunks(size_t n, R)(R r) if (isInputRange!R) {
    import std.range : chunks;
    import std.algorithm : map, filter;
    return r.chunks(n).filter!(a => a.length == n).map!(a => a.tuplify!n);
}


auto tuplify(size_t n, R)(R r) if (isInputRange!R) {
    import std.meta : Repeat;
    import std.range : ElementType;
    import std.typecons : Tuple;
    import std.array : front, popFront, empty;
    
    Tuple!(Repeat!(n, ElementType!R)) result;

    static foreach (i; 0..n) {
        result[i] = r.front;
        r.popFront();
    }
    assert(r.empty);

    return result;
}
```

Note that this also deals with the last chunk being a different size, if only by silently throwing it away. If this behavior is undesirable, remove the `filter`, and deal with it inside `tuplify` (or don't, and watch the exceptions roll in).

Comment: Nice, I was just about posting my own solution to this question but I accept your answer first :-) . I came up with an essentially very similar approach two hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

`chunks` and `slide` return `Range`s, not tuples. Their last element can contain less than the specified size, whereas tuples have a fixed compile time size.

If you need destructuring, you have to implement your own chunks/slide that return tuples. To explicitly add an index  to the tuple, use `enumerate`. Here is an example:

```
import std.typecons, std.stdio, std.range;

Tuple!(int, int)[] pairs(){
    return [
        tuple(1, 3),
        tuple(2, 4),
        tuple(3, 5)
    ];
}

void main(){
    foreach(size_t i, int start, int end; pairs.enumerate){
        writeln(i, ' ', start, ' ', end);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As BioTronic said using `map` is also possible:

```
foreach(i, start, end; intervals
                       .chunks(2)
                       .map!(a => tuple(a[0], a[1]))
                       .enumerate){
```

Comment: +1 because of mentioning the reduced chunk size of the last chunk. It's closer to the answer I wanted to get. I hoped for one standard library function or clever method (not necessarily in the OOP sense) which does this "chunks().map().enumerate()" scheme in one function call, in the same way as you can add an index when looping over simple Iterables with foreach. I'll add more detail to my question.

Comment: And I believe, your "map" example will fail, if the `intervals` range has an odd number of elements.

Comment: There is no "simple" one-function solution to your problem, as the combination of operations (especially with "drop the last one if it doesn't fit") is very specific and thus not a good fit for a standard library. If you expect an odd length interval list and want to remove the remainder, you can slice before grouping: `intervals[0 .. size_t(intervals.length/2)*2]`

Comment: Thank you, the slicing idea is good! However, in my point of view (at least when turning a range into a sequence of statically sized groups), I really would generally expect an implementation to cut off too small groups. That's only as long as the groups are *statically-sized* but converting a range into dynamically-sized groups is a different story where I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has me a little confused, so I'm sorry if I've misunderstood. What you're basically asking is if `foreach(a, b; [1,2,3,4].chunks(2))` could work, right?

The simple solution here is to, as you say, `map` from chunk to `tuple`:

```d
import std.typecons : tuple;
import std.algorithm : map;
import std.range : chunks;
import std.stdio : writeln;

unittest {
    pragma(msg, typeof([1,2].chunks(2).front));

    foreach(a, b; [1,2,3,4].chunks(2).map!(a => tuple(a[0], a[1]))) {
        writeln(a, ", ", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a "simple" solution but it will need changes of the lambda for the "map" when the chunk size changes. It doesn't provide an index to the foreach loop and it requires you to manually index each tuple element. Avoiding explicit indexed accesses is the main goal behind my question. In your example, I personally think, it's better style, to place a[0] and a[i] within the loop body and not within a "map" call.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time with BioTronic, I tried to code some own solution to this problem (tested on DMD). My solution works for slices (BUT NOT fixed-size arrays) and avoids a call to `filter`:

```cpp
import std.range : chunks, isInputRange, enumerate;
import std.range : isRandomAccessRange; //changed from "hasSlicing" to "isRandomAccessRange" thanks to BioTronics
import std.traits : isIterable;

/** turns chunks into tuples */
template byTuples(size_t N, M)
if (isRandomAccessRange!M) {   //EDITED
    import std.meta : Repeat;
    import std.typecons : Tuple;
    import std.traits : ForeachType;

    alias VariableGroup = Tuple!(Repeat!(N, ForeachType!M));    //Tuple of N repititions of M's Foreach-iterated Type
    /** turns N consecutive array elements into a Variable Group */
    auto toTuple (Chunk)(Chunk subArray) @nogc @safe pure nothrow
    if (isInputRange!Chunk) {       //Chunk must be indexable
        VariableGroup nextLoopVariables;    //fill the tuple with static foreach loop
        static foreach(index; 0 .. N) {
            static if ( isRandomAccessRange!Chunk ) {  // add cases for other ranges here
                nextLoopVariables[index] = subArray[index];
            } else {
                nextLoopVariables[index] = subArray.popFront();
            }
        }
        return nextLoopVariables;
    }
    /** returns a range of VariableGroups */
    auto byTuples(M array) @safe pure nothrow {
        import std.algorithm.iteration : map;

        static if(!isInputRange!M) {
            static assert(0, "Cannot call map() on fixed-size array.");
//          auto varGroups = array[].chunks(N);     //fixed-size arrays aren't slices by default and cannot be treated like ranges
            //WARNING! invoking "map" on a chunk range from fixed-size array will fail and access wrong memory with no warning or exception despite @safe!
        } else {
            auto varGroups = array.chunks(N);
        }
        //remove last group if incomplete
        if (varGroups.back.length < N) varGroups.popBack();
        //NOTE! I don't know why but `map!toTuple` DOES NOT COMPILE! And will cause a template compilation mess.
        return varGroups.map!(chunk => toTuple(chunk));     //don't know if it uses GC
    }
}

void main() {
    testArrayToTuples([1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]);
}

// Order of template parameters is relevant.
// You must define parameters implicitly at first to be associated with a template specialization
void testArrayToTuples(U : V[], V)(U arr) {

    double[] randomNumbers = new double[arr.length / 2];
    // generate random numbers
    foreach(i, double x, double y; byTuples!2(arr).enumerate ) {    //cannot use UFCS with "byTuples"
        import std.random : uniform01;
        randomNumbers[i] = (uniform01 * (y - x) + x);
    }
    foreach(n; randomNumbers) { //'n' apparently works despite shadowing a template parameter
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(n);
    }
}
```

Using elementwise operations with the slice operator would not work here because `uniform01` in `uniform01 * (ends[] - starts[]) + starts[]` would only be called once and not multiple times.

EDIT: I also tested some online compilers for D for this code and it's weird that they behave differently for the same code. For compilation of D I can recommend

- https://run.dlang.io/ (I would be very surprised if this one wouldn't work)
- https://www.mycompiler.io/new/d  (but a bit slow)
- https://ideone.com (it works but it makes your code public! Don't use with protected code.)

but those didn't work for me:

- https://tio.run/#d2 (didn't finish compilation in one case, otherwise wrong results on execution even when using dynamic array for the test)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_d_online.php (doesn't compile the static foreach)

Comment: There are some issues with this solution, which I'm going to attribute more to the language than to you. In the `byTuples` function, the  `varGroups` variable is saved on the stack, and when the function returns the reference is invalidated. This may lead to memory corruption at some point later. Compile with `-dip1000` (which I believe will be the default soon) to get an error there.

Comment: You're also using the `hasSlicing` trait to check if `Chunk` is indexable. As the name indicates, `hasSlicing` check if the type is slicable (`foo[1..3]`), while `hasIndexing` checks for indexability (`foo[2]`). I'm not aware of any types that have slicing but not indexing, but it's theoretically possible. This is not a big issue.

Comment: @BioTronic Oh, okay. I didn't know that. I'm still a bit new too D and it takes me a long time to find the library symbols which do what and *how* I'd like to have it.

Comment: Btw, I couldn't find `hasIndexing` in Phobos but instead `isRandomAccessRange` is used to check for an indexable range.

Comment: You're absolutely right, `isRandomAccessRange` is the one I was thinking of. I have no excuse. :p